# Installed .NET 6.0 SDKs not showing with dotnet --info or dotnet --list-sdks and commands depeding on SDK fail (Linux/Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, .net-core, ubuntu-22.04

After upgrade to latest dotnet, sdk stopped working. I try to reinstall the latest version but doesn't help.

```
$ dotnet --info

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround on [github issue #27129](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/27129#issuecomment-1214358108)：

1. Remove currently installed packages:

   ```bash
   sudo apt remove dotnet* aspnetcore* -y
   ```
2. Add a preference file in `/etc/apt/preferences`:

   ```bash
   sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences &&
   sudo echo "Package: *" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences &&
   sudo echo "Pin: origin \"packages.microsoft.com\"" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences &&
   sudo echo Pin-Priority: 1001 | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences
   ```
3. Install .NET 6 SDK again:

   ```bash
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```