# Why ASP.NET Core runtime doesn't recognize the installed SDKs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I have installed both the runtime and the sdk version 7.0 of dotnet from the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu website. The runtime -I think- works fine, but the SDK on the other hand, doesn't show up when I run this command:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

It doesn't show anything, and when I run this command:

```
dotnet --info
```

This is shown:

```
Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       (some hex value)

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/share/dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

I even gave sudo privileges, still doesn't show any SDKs.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04

The location of:
sdk: **/usr/share/dotnet.**
nside */usr/share/dotnet*, three directories:

```
-sdk 
-sdk-manifests
-templates
```

runtime: **/usr/lib/dotnet.** Inside */usr/lib/dotnet,* three directories and three files:

```
-host 
-packs 
-shared 

-dotnet  -executable-
-LICENSE.txt
-ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

Steps I have done:
1.

```
# Get Ubuntu version
declare repo_version=$(if command -v lsb_release &> /dev/null; then lsb_release -r -s; else grep -oP '(?<=^VERSION_ID=).+' /etc/os-release | tr -d '"'; fi)

# Download Microsoft signing key and repository
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$repo_version/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Install Microsoft signing key and repository
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Clean up
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Update packages
sudo apt update
```

2. 

```
apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0.
```

I didn't install the **runtime 7.0** manually, it was installed automatically with the command:

```
apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0.
```

- I tried changing both **DOTNET_ROOT**, and **PATH** environment variables to the location of sdk: **/usr/share/dotnet**. Expecting it to recognize the location of the sdk, but it didn't work.
- Installed a different sdk version (6.0), still didn't show up.
- Reinstalled both the runtime and sdk, still didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but it seems that I have some programs that I had on my machine conflicting with the SDKs I am installing and I should be giving the "packages.microsoft.com/" a higher priority in order to avoid the conflicts. This answer given by another user on stackoverflow has worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73360096/21749839